# using OVal validation framework in Java

Tags: java, validation, annotations, oval

I use OVal framework for validate business objects in my java projects.
please see validation class :

```
    public class ObjectValidation implements ObjectValidatable {

    private IValidator validator;
    private Map<String, String> errorMessages;

    public ObjectValidation() {
        validator = new Validator();
    }

    public boolean isValid() {
        if (validate().size() > 0)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public List<ConstraintViolation> validate() {
        return validator.validate(this);
    }

    public Map<String, String> getErrorMessages()
    {
        if(this.isValid()) return null;
        errorMessages =  new HashMap<String, String>(); 

        for(ConstraintViolation cv : this.validate())       
            errorMessages.put(cv.???, cv.getMessage());

        return errorMessages;
    }
}
```

AND

```
public class Account extends DomainObject {

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @NotBlank
    @Length(max = 5)
    private String userName; // How Get This ???


    private String password;
    private int securityId;
    private String securityAnswer;

        ...
     }
```

I have getErrorMessages that return Map
I want it return like this **userName-must be not null**

second section "must be not null" can get with cv.getMessage()

but first section that have validation annotation is my question

How get **userName** *or another fields* that have validation annotation ???

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the ConstraintViolation.getCauses() and the ConstraintViolation.getContext() method. They should provide what you need.